# AngularJS ng-repeat in div tag issue

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I Can't able to loop the array in div tag.

My JavaScript Source Code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var App = angular.module('drag-and-drop', ['ngDragDrop']);

      App.controller('oneCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.list1 = [];
        $scope.list2 = [];
        $scope.list3 = [];
        $scope.list4 = [];

        $scope.list5 = [
          { 'title': 'Item 1', 'drag': true },
          { 'title': 'Item 2', 'drag': true },
          { 'title': 'Item 3', 'drag': true },
          { 'title': 'Item 4', 'drag': true },
          { 'title': 'Item 5', 'drag': true },
          { 'title': 'Item 6', 'drag': true },
          { 'title': 'Item 7', 'drag': true },
          { 'title': 'Item 8', 'drag': true }
        ];

        // Limit items to be dropped in list1
        $scope.optionsList1 = {
          accept: function(dragEl) {
            if ($scope.list1.length >= 2) {
              return false;
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          }
        };
      });
    </script>
```

My HTML Source Code is

```
<div class="btn btn-droppable" ng-repeat="item in list5" data-drop="true" ng-model='list5' data-jqyoui-options="{accept:'.btn-draggable:not([ng-model=list5])'}"  jqyoui-droppable="{index: {{$index}}}">
    <div class="btn btn-info btn-draggable" data-drag="{{item.drag}}" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="list5" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},placeholder:true,animate:true}" ng-hide="!item.title">{{item.title}}</div>
</div>
```

Kindly assist me how to loop the array using angularjs ng-repeat in div tag. Is there is any error in my Source Code. Kindly fine tune it.

The Output Screen Shot is
[image: Error on Output]

Comment: you angular tag is visible in your image that's there must be error in your js part. check the console and provide us the error

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi - Yes I Can't able to fix. I'm new in angularJS. Kindly assist me.

Comment: If you can't provide us the error, how come we will know what's the problem. press F12 in your page. go to the console then check the error

Comment: As has already been mentioned, the screenshot you have included shows that angular did not load, and will definitely have an error in the browser console (F12).  There isn't anything obviously wrong with the code you provided, but you didn't provide a *complete* example, so it is impossible for others to know what is wrong without knowing the console error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I success to do the ng-repeat on the div element.

I removed the drag and drop because it not relevant for you'r question.

See the code below.

```js
 var App = angular.module('app', []);

       App.controller('oneCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
         $scope.list1 = [];
         $scope.list2 = [];
         $scope.list3 = [];
         $scope.list4 = [];

         $scope.list5 = [{
           'title': 'Item 1',
           'drag': true
         }, {
           'title': 'Item 2',
           'drag': true
         }, {
           'title': 'Item 3',
           'drag': true
         }, {
           'title': 'Item 4',
           'drag': true
         }, {
           'title': 'Item 5',
           'drag': true
         }, {
           'title': 'Item 6',
           'drag': true
         }, {
           'title': 'Item 7',
           'drag': true
         }, {
           'title': 'Item 8',
           'drag': true
         }];

         // Limit items to be dropped in list1
         $scope.optionsList1 = {
           accept: function(dragEl) {
             if ($scope.list1.length >= 2) {
               return false;
             } else {
               return true;
             }
           }
         };
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="oneCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in list5" ng-model='list5'>
      <div ng-model="list5">{{item.title}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```